# fast cumulative sum over array in C

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm

I am trying to write a **fast** method to calculate the cumulative sum over a one-dimensional array of type double, however my naive implementation is very slow and I'm not sure how I can speed up my method.

My first approach was to create an empty array of same dimensions and populate it with the respective cumulative sums in a for loop.

```
void cumsum_d(int size, double arr[size]) {
double* out = (double*)malloc(size*sizeof(double));
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    double temp = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < i+1; ++j) {
        temp += arr[j];
    }
    out[i] = temp;
}
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
    arr[i] = out[i];
}
free(out);}
```

My second attempt was to modify the array in place using recursion

```
void cumsum_d2(int size, double arr[size], int ind) {
if (ind == 0) {
    return;
}
double temp = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < ind+1; ++i) {
    temp += arr[i];
}
arr[ind] = temp;
cumsum_d2(size, arr, ind-1);}
```

For an array of length 1000 this has a runtime of approx. 1ms whereas e.g. the NumPy implementation  `NumPy.cumsum()` only takes around 60μs.

Are there any tips/tricks for how I can speed up my code, or are there any major flaws?

Comment: You don't need to calculate the smaller cumulative sums over and over. You already calculated it once, just add the current value. ...`accum[0] = values[0]; accum[1] = accum[0] + values[1]; accum[2] = accum[1] + values[2]; ...`

Comment: Think of [Schlemiel the Painter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky#Schlemiel_the_Painter's_algorithm). Don't forget to bring the bucket with you.

Comment: Of course it is slow, because you are making it `O(n^2)` instead of `O(n)`. Your `out[i+1]` should be calculated as `out[i] + arr[i+1]`.

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < size; ++i) arr[i] += arr[i - 1];` would be my first try.

Comment: I must've forgotten my bucket @FredLarson pointed out very appropriately... Thanks everyone for your help and sorry for this (in hindsight) trivial question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A already said in comments, this would be sufficient :

```
int main()
{
   double arr[10] =  {1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10.};
   
   for (char i=1; i<10; i++) {
       arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i-1]; 
       printf("%f\n", array[i]); 
   }
}
```

Comment: `array` is `double` , you can't print it with `%d` and `arr` is undefined.

Comment: pfff I make things too fast, double sorry